# What do you call a former soldier who has been injured in a war?

Tags: word-choice

There is a two-part word "Janbaz" (Persian جانباز) in Persian comprised of two parts i.e. Jan (i.e. life) + Baz (i.e. gamer) which refers to a former combatant who has sustained an injury during a war and is currently suffering from resulting disabilities. Is there a single English word used for such a person?

Comment: In the United States, the term "purple-heart veteran" is used, because the government awards purple-heart medals to all U.S. military personnel wounded in combat (or on duty).

Comment: It is a "war-wounded". But, using this word, you won't know if the combattant still suffers of his injuries.

Comment: "war invalid" also fits. If you write "war pensioner", your reader will undestand that the combattant receives a pension because he was wounded.

Comment: @JasonStack I"d say, "disabled war veteran."

Comment: In the US, "disabled veteran" is probably the most common term, assuming that the war wound did produce a disability.  Otherwise "Purple Heart veteran" or "war-wounded veteran" would probably be used.  There is no single word that I'm aware of, and, given the number of organizations (such as Disabled American Veterans) that exist tied to the concept, one would expect the term to be well-known if it existed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will go with ***disabled war veteran***.

> جانباز
>
> 1. (literally) one who would offer up their life.
> 2. disabled war veteran [Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D8%AC%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B2)
>
> war veteran ‎(*plural* war veterans): a person who has served in the armed
>   forces during a war. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/war_veteran)
>   [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=disabled+war+veteran%2Cdisabled+war+veterans&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdisabled%20war%20veteran%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdisabled%20war%20veterans%3B%2Cc0)
>
> ""*Janbaz* refers in Persian to someone who lays down their life for some
>   cause. But in the post-revolution period it has been specifically used
>   to refer to a disabled person from the Iran-Iraq War, and so I have
>   given the equivalent of 'a disabled war veteran' for it." [Iran, Iraq, and the Legacies of War](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=7SzIAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA115&lpg=PA115&dq=%22disabled+war+veteran%22+translated+into+persian+janbaz&source=bl&ots=LmeSJCPxQp&sig=_mtyBMxoBEIk2hyCLV7JuuKcKBA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CBsQ6AEwAGoVChMIvKGox6b_yAIVhvEUCh3U6QD9#v=onepage&q=%22disabled%20war%20veteran%22%20translated%20into%20persian%20janbaz&f=false)

Comment: Thanks. + for the book you linked to. It was interesting that a phrase similar to what I had in mind had been used already.

Answer (score 2):

"Disabled veteran" explicitly means the injury was permanent, while "Purple Heart veteran" explicitly means the injury was the direct result of enemy action. So if a combat veteran stubbed his toe while carrying ammunition, neither usage would be appropriate. In that case, then just "combat veteran" would be accurate.